# using filter operator with pipe - conditionally

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

i cant move the filter operator outside the map with a condition

```
return this.http.get('profili/usermenu')
                    .pipe(
                        map((menu: Menu[]) => {

                            if (this.appConfig.config.DisableRitiriDetails)
                                menu = menu.filter(item => !item.Description.includes('xxx'));
                            
                            const menuCreated: SidenavItem[] = this.menuSrv.populateMenu(menu); 
                            this.router.navigate([menuCreated[0].routeOrFunction]);
                            return new MenuSuccess(menuCreated);
                        }),
                        catchError(() => of(new LoginError(3)))
                    );
```

something like

```
return this.http.get('profili/usermenu')
                    .pipe(
                        filter((menu: Menu) => this.appConfig.config.DisableRitiriDetails || !menu.Description.includes('xxx')),
                        map((menu: Menu[]) => {
                            
                            const menuCreated: SidenavItem[] = this.menuSrv.populateMenu(menu); 
                            this.router.navigate([menuCreated[0].routeOrFunction]);
                            return new MenuSuccess(menuCreated);
                        }),
                        catchError(() => of(new LoginError(3)))
                    );
```

in this way it gives me error to the map((menu: Menu[])

Comment: It's because in the `filter` you said the argument was a `Menu`, while in the map you expect a `Menu[]` (menu array).

Comment: You're confusing the array method `.filter()` and the rxjs observable pipe operator `filter()`. In theory, an observable can emit many times, which is why the rxjs operator exists. This doesn't apply to you though since you're just doing a http get call which only emits one response (an array) and completed, but for example of the case of listening to clicks on a button, you may want to filter on whether each event is a right or left click. So filtering the observable doesn't make sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `filter` is:

> A function that evaluates each value emitted by the source Observable.

It is whole array, Menu[], not individuals items of the array. Return value is expected to be truthy/falsy.

Your intention is filter the items of the array, so you need another map function, see `pruneMenuItems` (I am not sure how to name function better as the original condition is confusing):

```
const pruneMenuItems = (menu: Menu[]) => this.appConfig.config.DisableRitiriDetails
      ? menu
      : menu.filter(item => !item.Description.includes('xxx'))

return this.http.get('profili/usermenu')
  .pipe(
    map(pruneMenuItems),
    map((menu: Menu[]) => {
      const menuCreated: SidenavItem[] = this.menuSrv.populateMenu(menu); 
      this.router.navigate([menuCreated[0].routeOrFunction]);
      return new MenuSuccess(menuCreated);
    }),
    catchError(() => of(new LoginError(3)))
  );
```